# How to print messages in BSD network stack code?

Tags: c, freebsd, bsd

I want to add some `printf` statements of my own in the BSD network stack. But after adding them I cannot see the messages coming up on the console of my machine. I tried to add some in the netisr ( sys/net/netisr.c ) . Cannot even find the already present `printf` statements. A noob at kernel programming.

```
 netsmp_lockinit(void *dummy)
  {      
          printf("Function %s   File %s : Line %d\n",__func__,__FILE__,__LINE__);
          rw_init_flags(&Netstack, "netsmp", RW_NETLOCK);
  }
```

Comment: please put what you did here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel can't use the C Standard I/O facilities. It must use a logging facility.
For example, `sys/netinet/in.c` uses

```
log(LOG_INFO, "in_scrubprefix: err=%d, old prefix delete failed\n", error);
```

to communicate to the world outside what happened.